# How to create an array of Type Variables, in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, generics

In Java it is possible to declare an array of type variables, but I'm not able to create the array. Is it impossible?

```
class ClassName<T> {
    {
        T[] localVar; // OK
        localVar = new T[3]; // Error: Cannot create a generic array of T
    }
}
```

Comment: Added to [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java/info)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generic type of array are not there in Java.
You can go for ArrayList

**Explanation :**

array in java are of covariant type.

> Java arrays have the property that there types are covariant , which means that an array of supertype references is a supertype of an array of subtype references.That is, `Object[]` is a supertype of `String[]` for example. As a result of covariance all the type rules apply that are customary for sub- and supertypes: a subtype array can be assigned to a supertype array variable, subtype arrays can be passed as arguments to methods that expect supertype arrays, and so on and so forth.Here is an example:

```
Object[] objArr = new String[10];// fine
```

> In contrast, generic collections are not covariant. An instantiation of a parameterized type for a supertype is not considered a supertype of an instantiation of the same parameterized type for a subtype.That is, a `LinkedList<Object>` is not a super type of `LinkedList<String>` and consequently a `LinkedList<String>` cannot be used where a `LinkedList<Object>` is expected; there is no assignment compatibility between those two instantiations of the same parameterized type, etc.Here is an example that illustrates the difference:

```
LinkedList<Object> objLst = new LinkedList<String>(); // compile-time error
```

Source: http://www.angelikalanger.com/Articles/Papers/JavaGenerics/ArraysInJavaGenerics.htm

Answer (score 2):

This is only possible in a language with reified generics, like [Gosu](http://gosu-lang.org).  Java has type erasure, so the type of T isn't available at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

```
T[] localVar = (T[])(new Vector<T>(3).toArray()); // new T[3];
```

Comment: This solution does not work. The array returned by the Vector API will always be an Object[]. Treating it as a T[] for arbitrary T will yield ClassCastException. You need to work from the Class<T> as described in other answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. You can do it if you have the `Class` object representing `T`, you can use `java.lang.reflect.Array`:

```
public static <T> T[] createArray(Class<T> clazz, int size) {
    T[] array = (T[]) java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(clazz, length);
    return array;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way that I got around this is by creating a different class to hold the type-Variable, then create an array of that class
eg.

```
    public class test<T>{
        data[] localVar = new data[1];
        private class data<E>{
            E info;
            public data(E e){ info = e; }
        }
        public void add(T e){ localVar[0] = new data<T>(e); }
    }
```

the code above cant be used for anything practical unless you want to add one item to an array, but its just shows the idea.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot initialize a generic type directly. However, you can create an array of Object type and cast it to generic array type as following:

```
class ClassName<T> {
    {
        T[] localVar = (T[]) new Object[3];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ClassName<T> {
    private T[] values;

    public void addValues(final T... values) {
        if(values != null && values.length > 0) {
            this.values = (T[]) Array.newInstance(values[0].getClass(), values.length);
            for (int idx = 0; idx < values.length; idx++) {
                this.values[idx] = values[idx];
            }
        }
    }
    public T[] getValues() {
        return this.values;
    }
}

@Test
public void soverflow() {
    // Generic type is a String
    ClassName<String> cn = new ClassName<>();
    cn.addValues("Kevin", "Kyle", "Hu");
    String[] names = (String[]) cn.getValues();

    // Generic type is an Integer
    ClassName<Integer> cn2 = new ClassName<>();
    cn2.addValues(1, 2, 3);
    Integer[] numbers = cn2.getValues();

    System.out.println(names[0]);
    System.out.println(numbers[0]);
}
```

Comment: Answers that contain only code are generally considered to be poor quality. Perhaps you can [edit] your answer and add some explanation of how it works?